# Are the circular dependency warnings in Angular really a problem?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For a while now Angular has supported a `showCircularDependencies` build flag (https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angular-devkitbuild-angular) that alerts you circular dependencies inside classes.

But are those warnings really a problem? Let's take a look at an example

```js
import {MyOtherService} from './my-other-service.ts';
@Injectable()
class MyService {
    constructor(private otherService: MyOtherService)
}
function calculate(): void {
    // some method that should be exported so it can be used without the service instance
}

export {MyService, calculate}
```

and file 2

```js
import {calculate} from './my-service.ts'
@Injectable()
class MyOtherService {
    constructor() {
        calculate();
    }
}
```

This will now cause a warning
`my-service.ts -> my-other-service.ts -> my-service.ts`

My question is, is this really problem? Because as far as I see JS is smart enough to only import the needed parts and is not causing a memory leak here.

And on a side note: for cases where it would cause problems for example `MyOtherService` injecting `MyService` in the constructor you will get hard build errors from Angular because it can't compile at all.
(And also if you look at the documentation link above you will notice that this option to even show the warnings will be deprecated coming Angular 14)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Extract the code into its own file and import it separately. Remove cyclic dependencies at all costs as it can lead to major problems.

**Explanation**

Personally, I think this is not a problem regarding if it works or not in the first place, but more an issue of code quality -> code coupling.

Let's take your example, but rename `MyService` to `BaseService`, and `MyOtherService` to `InjectedService`:

If we ignore the import and call to `calculate` for a moment, we are in the situation where `BaseService` depends on `InjectedService`. If you now change something in `InjectedService`, you always have to make sure, that nothing breaks in `BaseService`. But if you change something in `BaseService`, you don't have to worry about any implications for any other services.

If we now take the original example, you have a dependency in both directions (therefore the cyclic dependency). You are going to have to maintain always both services if you change anything to either one because stuff can break in both directions. At some point, you, or one of your coworkers, may forget to do that, and that's when bugs get introduced. Now the problem can get even worse, if the cyclic dependencies are indirect, meaning spanning over multiple files (`>2`; `e.g. A -> B -> C -> A`). Then it can get really complicated, and the smartness of JavaScripts module loading might be not enough anymore.

The solution to this problem is pretty straightforward. Extract the code you for `calculate` into its own file (it is a function anyway and has no connection to the class). Yes, it does result in an extra file with little content, but from a clean coding and maintainability standpoint, it is a much better option.

If you still think it is better the way you have it, you have the option to disable the warning in your `angular.json` file.

```
"defaults": {
    "apps": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Totally get your point. But my question is more angular is going to remove the detection overall in the next version. And extracting the `calculate` into a separate file is not solving the dependency. Because if I change calculate I still have to check both usages of that function

Comment: It solves the dependency in the way that you have a DAG (directed acyclic graph) as a dependency graph. You therefore can move `calculate` into its own module and even publish it in an extreme scenario, without the services being affected (other than changing the import). If the `calculate` method has a strong coupling to the base service, just create a static helper class like `BaseServiceHelper` or `BaseServiceUtil`. You would then have as a dependency tree:

`BaseServiceHelper <- BaseService`, `InjectedService <- BaseService`, `BaseServiceHelper <- InjectedService`